# In quel di Milano

Tags: idioms, etymology

Da dove deriva l'espressione "in quel di (luogo)" volta a indicare un luogo? È un espressione che sento spesso, e personalmente trovo fastidiosa. Spero sia dialettale.

Esempio:

> La conferenza si svolgerà in quel di Londra.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spero di non deludere Danny, ma ["*in quel di*"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quello/) è una [polirematica](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/parole-polirematiche_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) perfettamente legittima in lingua italiana, e [registrata](http://dizionario_italiano.enacademic.com/85179/quello). Più precisamente, è una [locuzione preposizionale](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/locuzioni-preposizionali_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/) e deriva da "*in quel territorio di*". Nel caso di Milano potrebbe forse derivare da "*in quel Ducato di*"?

Io trovo l'espressione gradevole perché per me, gusto personale, ha un sapore medioevale, affascinante. Certo l'espressione era usata anche in antichità, per esempio in [Leonardo Bruni - Della vita, studi e costumi di Dante](http://www.liberliber.it/mediateca/libri/b/bruni/della_vita_studi_e_costumi_di_dante/pdf/della__p.pdf) (1436).

Comment: Grazie! Sì, un po' sono rimasto deluso. Dove vivo io c'è un abuso di questa espressione, per questo la trovo fastidiosa. Per il resto, se è buon italiano, ben venga!